# app:processDebugResources Failed

Tags: android, android-studio, gradle, build

I'm just running my Android studio for the first time.
After I create a new project, I keep getting this error.
Please some should help me.

```
Execution failed for task ':app:processDebugResources'.
> com.android.ide.common.internal.Process.processExecption: failed to execute aapt
```

Comment: Where is your code? What have you tried so far?

Comment: I just created a new project with blank activity. It is still the default Hello world. I have not added any code yet